# show all other appearances by key in a new column of data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

A dataframe with clients and purchases

```
id  name  department
1   joe    fruit
2   peter  meat
3   joe    warehouse
4   marge  fruit
5   marge  meat
6   joe    pharmacy
```

I need a dataframe putting a row for every coincidence of the customer this way:

```
joe  fruit  joe warehouse  
joe  fruit  joe  pharmacy
peter meat
marge fruit marge meat
```

For every customer.

Tried dplyr::join and merge but to no avail

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, you mean you want to have unique combinations?

Comment: I mean, for every customer a row with first appearance (purchase) and besides other column with the subsequent purchases. One row per purchase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
full_join(
  df %>% group_by(name) %>% slice(1),
  df %>% group_by(name) %>% slice(-1),
  'name'
)
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 5
> # Groups:   name [?]
>    id.x name  department.x  id.y department.y
>   <int> <chr> <chr>        <int> <chr>       
> 1     1 joe   fruit            3 warehouse   
> 2     1 joe   fruit            6 pharmacy    
> 3     4 marge fruit            5 meat        
> 4     2 peter meat            NA NA
> ```

Or simply

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(name) %>% select(-id)
full_join(slice(df2, 1), slice(df2, -1), 'name')
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
> # Groups:   name [?]
>   name  department.x department.y
>   <chr> <chr>        <chr>       
> 1 joe   fruit        warehouse   
> 2 joe   fruit        pharmacy    
> 3 marge fruit        meat        
> 4 peter meat         NA
> ```

Comment: both worked. I have to study your code 'cause some things are unknown to me but really much appreciated